# How to find indices for all contiguous elements in an array that appear more than threshold

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find indices for all contiguous elements that occurrence more than Threshold in one dimensional integer array using c#

```
double[] x = new double[20]{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1};
```

I want to get indices for this x[] vector as the following for 0 values

```
threshold=4

start-index[0] =2
  end-index[0] =5

start-index[1] =8
  end-index[1] =11
```

i try to use this code, but there is many problems in it

```
public void myFunc(double[] x, ref List<int> start, ref List<int> end,int matchingVal,int threshold)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < threshold; j++)
            {
                if (x[i] == x[j] && x[i] == matchingVal)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;//no contiguous element
                }
                if (count >= threshold)
                {
                    start.Add(i);
                    end.Add(i + count);
                    count = 0;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to save each index for contiguous element that appears more than threshold (ex: value 0 and threshold 3)
 the first start index = 2
the second start index=5
and so on, and if possible to get end index of this contiguous elements

Comment: The code you posted has a `matchingVal` argument that you didn't mention in your requirements. Is it needed?

Comment: It's not that I can't understand you, it's that your question doesn't state a problem. From the vote to close dialog (emphasis mine): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Dev.Mahmood Did any of the answers we shared work for you? If so, please mark one of them as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), consider using `GroupAdjacent`.

An example is below. Basically, it takes the original array, uses `Select` to include the index, uses `GroupAdjacent` to group adjacent values together, uses `Where` and `Count` to check there are at least 4 adjacent values, then uses `Select` to project an anonymous type including the value and its first and last index (this can be changed to project to whatever concrete type you want). *Then `string.Join` is used to write it to the console so you can see the results.*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] x = new double[20] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };

            var results = x.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .GroupAdjacent(z => z.value)
                .Where(z => z.Count() >= 4)
                .Where(z => z.Key == 0) // it is unclear whether you want to filter for specific values - if so, this is how to do it
                .Select(z =>
                    new { value = z.Key, firstIndex = z.First().index, lastIndex = z.Last().index })
                .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Select(z => $"{z.value} - {z.firstIndex} - {z.lastIndex}")));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills, good one!
Can't we merge the 2 `where` condition into one?

Comment: @RSF You could yes - I have purposely kept them separate since the OP is not 100% clear whether the second `Where` is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** added more tests and fixed an issue thanks to [@AntonínLejsek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4959221/anton%C3%ADn-lejsek)

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<(int start, int finish)> GetStuff(int thresh, double[] ary)
{
   int start = 0, count = 1;

   for (var i = 0; i < ary.Length - 1; i++, count++)
      if (ary[i] == ary[i + 1])
      {
         if (count == 1) start = i;
      }
      else
      {
         if (count >= thresh) yield return (start, i);
         count = 0; 
      }

   if (count >= thresh) yield return (start, ary.Length-1);
}
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var tuple in GetStuff(3,ary))
   Console.WriteLine($"start : {tuple.start}, finish : {tuple.finish}");
```

**Output**

```
var ary = new double[] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 }; 

start : 2, finish : 5
start : 8, finish : 11
start : 12, finish : 14
start : 15, finish : 17
```

---

```
var ary = new double[] { 1, 1, 1 ,0 };

start : 0, finish : 2
```

---

```
var ary = new double[] { 1, 1, 1 };

start : 0, finish : 2
```

Comment: the output I want
2,
8
 just the first index of contiguous series that have the same element (ex: 0) more than threshold (ex: 3)

Comment: { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} gives a result 1-5. Am I missing something?